# RewriteCond ignore web not website

Tags: apache

I understand this might not be the best naming scheme, but I have a folder called web on my server and I want the rewrite to ignore that folder with my .htaccess file. The rest is being redirected for codeigniter, and I have a /website that needs to be redirected, but if I put in the exception like below then it ignores web and /website.

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|files|web|image)
```

Perhaps there is a better way of wording the question so it's more generalized and can be used more than once, I don't know of a way though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is undoubtedly a cleaner solution, but something like this may work in the meantime.
Idea is to split into two conditions, one for directories one for files. The trailing / on the first condition means only those exact directories should get processed.

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(web|files|image)/
RewriteCond $1 !^index.php
```

Note this is untested, but hopefully will give you an idea.

Comment: Worked great, and it was cleaner thanks, because I actually had a lot more folders/files in that RewriteCond that I didn't include in my question.